# Easy Riddles #5: GAH THERES A BEE ON ME

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> In my hand there is a black and yellow bug.
>
> In my eye there is something else.

What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> beauty (in the eye of the bee holder)

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Beauty ?

In my hand there is a black and yellow bug.

> Bee

In my eye there is something else.

> Beauty lies in the eyes of the beholder.